# xcode size classes tool

Tags: xcode, size-classes, xcode13

I'm using xcode 13 and UIKit.

According to the tutorial I'm doing, there should be a size classes tool, in my "view as" bar, but I can't see it. Has this changed?

How I'm I supposed to set up constraints for a specific size class?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found the solution here: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-13-vary-for-traits/

You use the "installed" feature on the constraints